# Laravel 5.4 Using calculated field for sorting, querying, and displaying

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm a beginner Laravel programmer and just came across this problem:
I have a `people` table with the fields `firstName`, `middleName` and `lastName`, which I concatenate in a function called `getAliasByLastNameAttribute()` in the `People` model. `('alias_by_last_name' = lastName, firstName middleName...)`. I then appended this new field to the `People` model using:

```
protected $appends = [
    'alias_by_last_name'
];
```

So far, so good, and I get exactly what I want. Now I need to use this calculated field value throughout my application, so that the user can see it in list elements in other related models forms, select it in select elements in it´s own and other related models, and to filter queries on it´s value in different placees. How can I do this without having to save the value to the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use concatenated fields in sorting you need concat it in your query, like:

`->orderBy(DB::raw('concat(firstName, " ", middleName, " ", lastName)'))`

To not to DRY you can define it in your model:

```php
class People extends Model {

    public static function aliasName() {
        return DB::raw('concat(firstName, " ", middleName, " ", lastName)');
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```php
$people = People::orderBy(People::aliasName())->get();
```

Of course, you can always access `alias_by_last_name` that you define in accessor `getAliasByLastNameAttribute()`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I just realized that if I populate a select element using a query like: $query = App\People::orderBy(alias_by_last_name)->get(); I don´t see the aliasByLastName bit, it just shows a blank space. If instead I build the query as: $query = App\People::all()->sortBy(aliasByLastName)->get(); I then am able to show the alias correclty. I'm not sure what exactly is different, but it works this way.